# What would an external vertex look like on a Feynman diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

as you can tell from the question I am new to Feynman diagrams. I am trying to understand ways a diagram could be disconnected (besides vacuum bubbles). I am mainly trying to understand what an external vertex would look like? I have been trying to find a definition or some examples to get an idea but couldn't see anything helpful.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry its not, just in my notes from my lecture course I see diagrams being talked about as connected, and am interested in being able to distinguish them from one another. I had seen vacuum bubbles mentioned as one reason for disconnect (which I can recognise) but did not follow any other like external vertex.

Comment: @Qmechanic Not the lecture notes I have but provides an example of what I am talking about. http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/three.pdf  Like fig 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*External vertices* in a Feynman diagram presumably refer to

- 1-vertices/external sources

and/or

- vertices with amputated legs.